# Rust lifetime of elements inside Arc<Vec<>>

Tags: rust

I come from a Golang background and I'm working on a project in Rust that has the following setup:

I have a standard producer/consumer setup based on 2 channels: "work channel" and "result channel".
The producer thread sends work to the work channel and receives results from the result channel.
The consumer thread receives work from the work channel and sends results to the result channel.

I created a Minimal Reproducible Example of the issue I'm having in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=920054bc5f43133718bc55abaa74e804) (same pasted below). [note: I'm aware this is a stupid way to solve this specific problem; in the real-world problem I have a vector as input and I use some of the elements as keys to a hashmap that's returned containing results of computations done for the elements]

The issue I'm having is that I want to reference the elements inside the input vector in the output vector.
In the MRE, I have a `Vec<User>` as input and a filtered `Vec<User>` as output. Ideally I'd like to have a `Vec<&User>` as output, just referencing the input elements **so I don't have to clone them** (`underage.push(el.clone());`).

I believe I understand what causes this issue, but the only solution I can think of is passing `Arc<Vec<Arc<User>>` as input, which looks awful.

Is there any a way to return `Arc<Vec<&User>>` connecting the lifetime of the references of the elements inside the vector with the lifetime of the vector?

Thanks!

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct User {
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<User> = vec!(
        User{age: 10},
        User{age: 20},
        User{age: 15},
        User{age: 18},
    );
    let arc_my_vec = Arc::new(my_vec);
    
    // this is a thread that listens for work on a rx_work channel
    // and puts the result of the work on a tx_result channel
    let (tx_work, rx_work) = channel();
    let (tx_result, rx_result) = channel();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let users: Arc<Vec<User>> = rx_work.recv().unwrap();
            
            let mut underage = vec![];
            for el in users.iter() {
                if el.age < 18 {
                    underage.push(el.clone());
                }
            }
            tx_result.send(underage).unwrap();
        }
    });
    
    let this_vec = Arc::clone(&arc_my_vec);
    // put work on the channel that's followed by the thread
    tx_work.send(this_vec).unwrap();

    // receive the result from the thread work
    let underage = rx_result.recv().unwrap();
    dbg!(underage);

    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: What's so awful about `Arc<Vec<Arc<User>>>` it immediately tells me that both the users and the vector are shared, and does accomplish what you want, bind the lifetime of `User` to all same users in the vector.

Comment: I'm new to rust, so perhaps `Arc<Vec<Arc<User>>>` is "normal", but it smells to me. In any case, the link you provided gave me a better understanding about why I can't do what I was trying ("This rules out mutating vectors, which may cause a reallocation and a move of the heap-allocated values"). I haven't considered this case, but it makes me think I could use a immutable vector (my use-case supports that) and perhaps there would be a cleaner solution (I don't know which )

Comment: Do you actually need the outer `Arc`? Both the channels in your example could be `Vec<User>` and work fine without cloning, and if you need multiple references to each `User`, you could have `Vec<Arc<User>>`. But it isn't clear why you need multiple references to the `Vec`. You could also send individual `Arc<User>` through the channels which removes the need for `Vec` altogether.

Comment: In my real-world scenario I need to iterate over the input elements in the main thread also, which is why I have `Arc<Vec<User>>` instead of moving `Vec<User>` to the channel.

Comment: I mentioned `Vec<Arc<User>>` smelled to me, and I thought a bit more on how to explain why that is. My main argument is that this couples the producer and the consumer more strongly: my producer API now needs to produce vectors of `Vec<Arc<User>>` even if for other use-cases `Vec<User>` would do. Just wrapping the API result around an `Arc` is cheap and can be done from by the user of the API, but the same is not true for internal elements.

Comment: Could the spawned thread just return a vector of indices? The main thread does keep a reference to the original vector after all.

Comment: Maybe you should add some more details how both threads interact to avoid talking around a XY-problem.

Comment: I second the idea of returning a vector of indices. Another option, if the `User` struct doesn't hold too much data, would be to just clone them. Usually we want to avoid cloning, but there can be cases where `Arc<T>` is actually _slower_ than just having a few copies of `T`.

Comment: If the channel owns the `User`s, you cannot depend on them for the output, but you can send `Arc<Vec<&User>>` (by using scoped threads) and then the output can be `Vec<&User>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using here  `Arc<Vec<User>>` to safely share the user data across threads without cloning the entire vector; and instead of passing the whole user objects, I pass a vector of indices `Vec<usize>` to the worker thread. This approach significantly reduces memory overhead.

Try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b86c88a907339a51a8a9e7b4fc4970de) :

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<User> = vec![
        User { age: 10 },
        User { age: 20 },
        User { age: 15 },
        User { age: 18 },
    ];
    let arc_my_vec = Arc::new(my_vec);

    // Specify the type of messages for the work channel
    let (tx_work, rx_work): (std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Vec<usize>>, std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Vec<usize>>) = channel();
    let (tx_result, rx_result) = channel();

    let arc_my_vec_clone = Arc::clone(&arc_my_vec);
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        while let Ok(indices) = rx_work.recv() {
            let underage_indices: Vec<usize> = indices
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|&i| arc_my_vec_clone[i].age < 18)
                .collect();

            tx_result.send(underage_indices).unwrap();
        }
    });

    // Send the indices of the vector to the worker thread
    let indices: Vec<usize> = (0..arc_my_vec.len()).collect();
    tx_work.send(indices).unwrap();

    // Receive the result from the worker thread
    let underage_indices = rx_result.recv().unwrap();
    let underage_users: Vec<&User> = underage_indices
        .iter()
        .map(|&i| &arc_my_vec[i])
        .collect();

    dbg!(underage_users);

    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the discussion and the suggestions.

For future reference, while I believe using indexes as reference to the elements a valid approach, for my use-case I ended up returning a (input_vector, output_vector) tuple, having the corresponding indexes. When some items need to be filtered out from the input vector (as in my example), the output_vector may store an Option with value None.

Another alternative I considered was providing, as input, a Vec (for example, Vec); the output would be provided empty and would be filled by the worker.

Of course none of this makes much sense for a simple task such as checking the age of an user, but I hope the concept is understandable for more long-running tasks such as calling an external API for each user.